# Docker container using all system resources

Tags: fedora, docker, rtorrent

I'm trying to start a docker image on my machine (fresh fedora 37 server (with kernel and arch: 6.0.8-300.fc37.x86_64 also tried on aarch64 - same problem) install, with docker (20.10.21) and for some reason it uses all the resources (cpu, ram) like it was a fork bomb (except it using all ram too). The image what I try to run is `docker run -it --rm jesec/rtorrent` I am interested why this is happening in general, my intention is not to run this specific image. Also it is not behaving the same way on different machines (the OS is identical), on some machines I get:

> rtorrent: std::bad_alloc